# Maven - differences between dependencies inside plugin and outside?

Tags: maven

I've come across some sample code which specifies dependencies inside the plugin tag like this :

```
   <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.8</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
```

It look strange to me because mostly I see people put the dependencies tag outside the build tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add `<dependency>` to project it is available to that project depending on its scope (compile, test, runtime, etc)

But  when you add `<dependency>` inside plugin's execution you are making that artifact available to that plugin in classpath at runtime

**For example:**

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>check my sources</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>compile</phase>
      </execution>
  </executions>
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>checkstyle</groupId>
        <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

in this snippet `checkstyle:checkstyle:4.4` is being available to `maven-checkstyle-plugin` at runtime

---

**Read More**

- [How to override a plugin's dependency in Maven](http://blog.sonatype.com/2008/04/how-to-override-a-plugins-dependency-in-maven/#.U8GCGajR1I4)

Comment: So if I export my project , those dependencies inside plugin will not be included because it use for that plugin only ?